# How would i write this python code in java

Tags: java, python, json, api

i am trying to get json data from an api in java, i know how to do this with python but i am doing a project in java and i'm clueless, i don't know where to start.

Python Code:

```
url2 = f"https://api.hypixel.net/status?key={APIKEY}&uuid=" + returnUuid
res = requests.get(url2)
data = res.json()
    if data["session"] is None:
        return None

onlinestatus = (data["session"]["online"])

    if onlinestatus is False:
        theNewLineString = "\n"
        lastLogout_string = "LastLogout: "
        log_out = int(data2["player"]["lastLogout"])

return str("Online: ") + "`" + "False"
```

How would i do that in java?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your main problem is finding a way to obtain information from a URL in java. If this is the case:

You'll want to use Java's URLConnection class. You can call:

```
URL url2 = new URL("https://www.google.com");
URLConnection urlConn = url2.openConnection();
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(in);
```

You can then scrape through the data using methods like `String line = buff.readLine();`

If you're looking to access specific contents on the webpage, you'll need to scrape the html and this can be a bit complicated. APIs like DJNativeSwing make this a lot easier to do (but require you to download a JAR and add it to your referenced libraries).

Answer (score 0):

1.Add below dependency into pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. You have to use RestTemplate or WebClient for API calls.

> ```
>      RestTemplate restTemplate=new ReastTemplate();
>
>   restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.hypixel.net/status?key={APIKEY}&uuid="+ returnUuid);
> ```

In the above case, you can get a response from a particular service.